# Как запустить проект vscode в терминале?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code

Перерыл кучу сайтов и видео, но никак не могу найти решение. 
Мне нужно в линуксе запустить С# проект, написанный в vscode через терминал, но я не знаю как выглядит скомпилированный проект, не знаю где он лежит и, тем более, как запустить его без участия vscode.
Заранее спасибо :3

Comment: У приложения на шарпе есть файлик sln - это файл решения. Вам надо его скормить тулкиту dotnet. Как правильно это сделать - гуглите, сам не в курсе. Между делом, для разработки на линуксе рекомендую использовать JetBrains Rider.

Comment: В интернете полно информации о том, как запустить консольное приложение (я так полагаю, у вас именно консольное приложение). Например, [вот](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-c-sharp-console-application-and-debug-in-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: `dotnet run` из папки с проектом